# invoice order items file path in magento?

Tags: php, magento

in magento invoice order items i want to show product price, qty and subtotal. I changed the order items in the below file path
/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/email/order/invoice/items.php
But no change. Anyone help me where and how to change the order items?

Comment: One simple trick to see from which file the invoice order items are displayed, is to enable the template path hints and then send the email, you will be able to see the path hints in the email template as well.

Answer (score 0):

First you should not change the magento core files. The best ways to override a template is to add a custom package with a custom theme. This theme has the base/default theme as parent theme(you can define this in the theme.xml).

Once you added your own Package, you can copy the template from base/default, insert it in your theme and then make your changes.

Of course your theme has to be applied in the magento backend.

Hope this helps.

-David